# How to horizontally center divs with auto widths when using inner elements as display: block?

Tags: css

I have something like this:

```
[ [span][link]              ]
```

but I would like something like this:

```
[       [span][link]        ]
```

Where the `<span>` and `<a>` element inside `<div>` element are centered in the middle horizontally

`span` and `a` element have auto width

`div` has hardcoded width 250px

How to do that?

My current CSS code is not working, it's centered to the left ;(:

```
a {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

span {
    float: left;
}

div {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div>
   <span>Name</span>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @JeffNoel No, it's different, there they have percentage I have defined size in pixels.

Comment: If you want the span and link centered in the div, why are you floating them? Also why is the link set to display block and the div is inline?

Comment: @j08691 because of the graphics and styling, it has to be that way

Comment: @dmn77 This is non-sense. [**Try it this way**](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/FAyrE/).

Comment: @JeffNoel I need to have link and span to be `display: block`. It's very different than the question you are pointing me with the duplicate.

Comment: @dmn77 I am **sorry**, but what you want to achieve is impossible. You can't center two elements within a container element with them being `display:block;`, floated without any spacer elements beside them. Might be possible in `HTML7.01`.

Comment: @dmn77 : WHY?? inline-block gives you the exact same functionalities, just more suitable for your question. You can't insist on not changing your HTML, keeping `a and span` with `display: block` and `float:left` and expect things to work magically.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inline-block` [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
<div class="outer">
   <span>Name</span>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span, a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: yellow;
    width: 500px;
    float:left;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bej7E/2/)

Comment: it's not working for me ;(

Comment: No, span and link should be inside of the div. No other elements are allowed to use.

Comment: Try to add `display: block;` to link and span it will not be working.

Comment: @dmn77 Do you even know what `display:block` does? an element being a `block` will kick all other elements away from his horizontal lane.

Comment: @Itay I want to style the block element, if it's only inline I can not float: left and use custom height and width if necessary. That's a limit of non-block elements.

Comment: @dmn77: You can freely give `inline-block` custom height and width. It's not just `inline`. For further reading: [What’s the Deal With Display: Inline-Block?](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/), [display - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: @Itay but I need float left, because I have many links not just one. everything it's one under the other. I need to have all the elements in one line, not everyone on the separate row ;(. How can I do that?

Comment: @dmn77 You're not reading the links I give you, and you do not understand what `inline-block` display is. Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Bej7E/3/) demo. It has many links without floating...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floats from the `a` and the `span` and instead float the divs. Try replacing your CSS with this:

```
a {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}

div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```